# Format float to be inserted into MySQL decimal(6,5) field

Tags: php, mysql

I need to format a floating point number in PHP so it can be inserted into a column in a table which is of type decimal(6,5).

So,

20 would get formatter to 20.00000

20.5 would get formatted to 20.50000

How to do it in PHP?

Comment: You don't need to format it at all...

Comment: FYI, you cannot store `20` in the column of type `DECIMAL(6,5)` -- `SQL Error (1264): Out of range value`

Comment: probably what you want is `decimal(11,5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the float inherent precision error, 
cast first to decimal(9,2), then to decimal(6,5).

Answer (score 1):

To format a number just use

```
<?php
echo number_format(20, 5); //returns 20.00000
echo number_format(20.5, 5); //returns 20.50000
?>
```

But you don't need to do that to insert into a MySQL DB.

Comment: Careful with `number_format`, as given here it might insert a thousands separator! See [number_format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: The 2nd parameter it's for decimal: 
`string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 0 ] )` Am I wrong?

Comment: @bart Yes, be very careful - I just ran in this bug, when a different number ended up in database...